# What difference between void(void) and void(*)(void)?

Tags: c++, function, types, function-pointers

`void(*)(void)` is a function pointer while I suppose `void(void)` is also a way to represent function type. It is used as template parameter in `std::function` <functional>

What is `void(void)` and how it is different from `void(*)(void)`?

Comment: A `void(*)(void)` is the address of a `void(void)`, which is the type of a function itself.  However, just as the name of an array is implicitly converted to a pointer [to its first element] in some cases, so is the name of a function.   For example, if we have a function declared `func(void(*)())` and a function declared `f()`, a statement that calls `func(f)` implicitly converts `f` to a pointer, so `func(f)` has the same effect as `func(&f)`.

Comment: What's the difference between `int*` and `int`? The syntax for functions is more complicated, but the underlying concept is the same.

Answer (score 3):

> What is `void(void)` and how it is different from `void(*)(void)`?

They are **distinct types**. Although the former(`void(void)`) can be implicitly converted to the latter(`void(*)(void)`) in many contexts.

The type `void(void)` is called a **function type**. The following are also function types:

```
int (int, int) //this is a function type
void(int)      //this is a function type as well
```

On the other hand, `void (*)(void)` is a *pointer to a function type*.  That is, it is a pointer that points to a function with `0` parameters and return type of `void`.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

- The `void(void)` is a specification of a function type, it's
  signature.
- The `void(*)(void)` is a pointer to function.

These are distinct.

---

First, let's start by saying, that sometimes the `void(void)` will be automatically treated as a pointer to function (i.e. in a parameter list). We still can be explicit and use the `void(*)(void)`, but the `void(void)` will be an **equivalent** in these cases.

```
// Here, we explicitly state that the f is a pointer to function
void foo(void (*f)(void), int i); 
// Equivalent, f is automatically treated as a pointer to the function
void foo(void f(void), int i);
```

This will **not be the case** for the mentioned `std::function` for example. The types of the two **are different**, yet may have similar behavior (i.e. we can use the function call operator on a pointer to function).

```
void bar();

// Prints 1
std::cout << std::is_same<void(void), decltype(bar)>::value << '\n'; 
// Prints 1 as well
// Note the pointer type specifier
std::cout << std::is_same<void(*)(void), decltype(bar)*>::value << '\n';
// Prints 0
// Note the absence of the pointer type specifier
std::cout << std::is_same<void(*)(void), decltype(bar)>::value << '\n';
```

And particularly:

```
// Ok
std::function<decltype(bar)> fn1 = bar;
// error: variable ‘std::function<void (*)()> fn2’ has initializer but incomplete type
std::function<decltype(bar)*> fn2 = bar;
```

Note, that we can however "store" a pointer to a **member function** in `std::function`, but even then the template's parameter still won't be of a pointer to function type, but a plain function signature.

```
struct MyType {
    void func(int) {}
};

int main() {

    // Note, we can't have a member function without an instance of the type
    // Thus we specify the usually implicit first param and the explicit int param
    std::function<void(MyType&, int)> fn_mem = &MyType::func;
    MyType my_object;
    fn_mem(my_object, 21);
    
}
```

For more on `std::function` please refer to the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). In short, the use of the `std::function` instead of the function pointers has the same moto as using the smart pointers instead of the raw pointers.

You may wonder on other uses of the `void(void)` or `int(int)` style function type specifications, so here's another example you may see often:

```
using func_t = int(int);
// func_ptr_func return a pointer to the func_t type alias
func_t* func_ptr_func();
```

---

N.B. unlike in the case of a parameter, the compiler won't treat the function type in a return as a pointer to function type. Thus, we must explicitly specify the pointer type in case of the return.

```
// Here, baz is a function that doesn't take any agruments
// And returns a pointer to a function that takes an int argument and "returns" void
void (*baz())(int);
```

Comment: So you copied the "they are distinct" portion from my answer and added it as an TLDR at the beginning in your answer?

Comment: @AnoopRana definitely, as I always do.

Comment: Why plagiarize?

Comment: @AnoopRana it was not the case, it was a tl;dr excerpt of my probably too elaborate answer. Why put ego in here?

Comment: You already admitted that **a)** you copied it from my answer and **b)** you always do this. Moreover, your original answer did not say anything about these types being distinct. You only discussed that one is convertible to the other. Also, this is more than about ego. Just copy/pasting from another answer by phrasing in your words is not right. **I had explained things in my answer that you didn't in yours and vise versa. So why copy each others answers?**

Comment: @AnoopRana The mentioned by you *a* and *b* refer to my ironic, comments which I probably should've made as plain and as unironic as possible. I do not admit that I've copied anything except for the code excerpts from my text editor and the link to the reference.  If there's a resemblance, then it is the tail and not the head of my narrative. I will be inclined to take the time to see how the community looks at the issue, by voting and commenting.

Comment: The evidence speaks for itself. The first  two bullet points of your answer are exactly the same as the explanation given in the first few lines of my answer. You have just formatted them to be shown as a bullet list. **Doing this devalues other people's(in this case mine) answer**

Comment: @AnoopRana as I said we'll see. If the community says that I'm in the wrong, I will admit it. As for my current position, I see no wrong.

Comment: Sure let the SO community decide and see how you changed sides from *"definitely, as i always do"* to *"i do not admit that i've copied..."*.

Answer (score 0):

for `void fun(){}`, `std::is_same_v<void(void)>, decltype(fun)>` is true; and `std::is_same_v<void(*)(void)>, decltype(&fun)>` is true. In fact, those are their real types. However, the standard approve you convert an object that has type `void(void)` to `void(*)(void)` implicitly (so you can even write `(******funptr)()`), that's why we always confuse them.